# Increase width of submit button (when viewed on non-mobiles)

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

**How can I increase the width of my submit butotn when viewed on non-mobile devices?**

[image: https://wb.workbooks.com/resources/=QzM/example-image.jpg]

It's an responsive form wrapped in an iFrame embedded on a landing page.

**CSS Code:**

```
.loudbutton, .quietbutton {
width: 50%;
height: 40%;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: rgb(79, 111, 163);
    border: none;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    float: none;
    min-width: 203px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/xpepn72r/

**Live preview link** - http://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/content/2371060669?portalId=155045&_preview=true&preview_key=w1at_hmF&__hstc=20629287.a9dcced3bbb4addd0a40a4006db38d92.1449656514144.1450454450316.1450690785211.14&__hssc=20629287.21.1450690785211&__hsfp=3888868638

Comment: Already I see this, as 100% on the given fiddle. Whats the matter?

Comment: Please see live link (works fine on JSFiddle but not in practice due to the limitations of the Hubspot landing page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this?

```
.loudbutton{
   width: 100%;
}
input.field.text{
   width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks Trix, please see above, I believe this maybe the answer.

Comment: Absolute hero!

Thanks! Would you mind explaining to me why thus worked?

Comment: Yes, you had some form elements in your iframe form, which also need to get full width, as below the mentioned browser width, the form expands to the total available width of the page

Answer (score 2):

Add `width: 100%` to the submit button

Comment: Thanks, works great until the page is scaled to around 737px (submit button at 504px) at which point the submit button leaps out.

Still looks better than before, thanks Hans!